# PWA workbox background sync queue requests queue object accessibility

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, offline, workbox

Can we access the Workbox background sync queue object in outside service worker file, in any of my application files say index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the [BroadcastChannel API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/broadcastchannel), something like this:

```
// From Service Worker, connect to the channel named "my_bus".
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('my_bus');
// Send a message on "my_bus".
channel.postMessage('This is a test message.');

// From client, listen for messages on "my_bus".
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('my_bus');
channel.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Received', e.data);
};
```